# Trouble installing lxml in osx 10.6 using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, osx-snow-leopard

I'm using Python 2.7 to try and install lxml. I've tried using pip and easy_install. I have homebrew and xcode 4.2. When I try installing with pip I get this error

```
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

When I try with easy_install I get

```
unable to execute gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

However when I do 
    gcc -v

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~3/src/configure --disable-        
checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man - -  
enable-      languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform- 
name=/^[cg][^.-   ]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 - - 
enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.1~3/dst-  
llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-
darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

So I have gcc 4.2, but there is something wrong with it.

Comment: "$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2"

That will make the necessary command available and might just work.